# Led ON on Spike Guard Even When Switch is OFF

Tags: wiring, electrical, electricity, bad-wiring

I have this spike guard and it's middle led is ON even when the spike guard switch is off. I can see there are various combinations of the led and their meaning. But I see the middle led on when the switch is OFF. Can anyone tell me if anything is of concern here?

[image]

Comment: Weird. LEDs 101 = All OK so 010= not OK?  maybe ground and Neutral reversed or noisy ground?

Comment: Does a filled circle mean on or off, that's the question.

Comment: it's the top row ... all OK

Comment: It isn't......the bulbs should glow..they do glow as 101 when the spike guard is ON.the image I have attached is when the Spike Guard is OFF

Comment: Maybe 010 is normal for switch power off (?)

Comment: Idk..I turned off the main FUSE of my circuit board to see if the middle led still glows, and guess what? IT does glow as 010! I'm scared

Comment: no need to be scared.  Plug in a light with power off to verify. not shown but 010 must be normal for PWR SWITCH OFF  but Pwr avail to turn ON then 101 when ON then Fuse blown ON when removed with 101

Comment: This is how it looks like when the SWITCH is ON. It looks like 101 but the middle 0 is a bit glowing so 111? Doesn't make sense? [Image][1] [1]: https://imgur.com/gallery/6LLRa7P

Comment: I'm adding some more information idk if it's needed. My brother has observed when he charges his laptop and the spike guard has the middle led ON he gets electrocuted when he touches metal parts of his laptop. I have experienced the same with USB devices when plugged to the computer.

Comment: Read the fabulous data sheet. We're not a support group for electrical products you might have bought ten years ago.

Comment: It's not even a year since my parents bought it:_( I'm not worried about the spike guard, I'm worried if my house wiring is screwed

Comment: @TomCarpenter Seems to be [filled-in = on](https://i.imgur.com/2XwHRuG.png) as you'd expect.

Comment: Is the device connected to earthed/grounded outlet? Does the laptop charger have 2-prong ungrounded plug or 3-prong grounded plug?

Comment: @Justme it's a 3 pin. Grounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the indicators would be connected.

[image]

And this would be the logic.

[image]

Instead of indicators 2 & 3 coming on for 'Line / Neutral Reverse', only indicator 2 would come on with the switch in the 'off' position.

That appears to be a design oversight!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like normal behaviour.

010 for Power Off
101 for Power On  not 111. thats just optical crosstalk

The laptop leakage is normal 0.5mA RF leakage filter to earth ground  on the charger to reduce EMI and is safe. but if user is earth grounded and DC charger is floating , there is transformer RF leakage to DC where you can feel electricity in a small spot like your wrist or knee but not whole hand.This is current limited by safe Plastic HV capacitors from line and Neutral to ground and series inductors to limit the RF noise current and block 50 / 60 Hz line voltage.  So it is the harmonic noise that is being felt. This is normal.  To avoid it connect laptop to earth gnd thru external LCD or just insulate yourself a bit better with socks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I'm relieved now:_)